# Filter using AND condition based on a single column

Tags: r, dplyr

This is my sample dataframe

```
df <- dput(head(Only_mesh,40))
structure(list(PMID = c(1617318, 1691132, 1691132, 1691132, 1691132, 
1691132, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 1691134, 
1828453, 1828453, 1861532, 1861532, 2031969, 2031969, 2031969, 
2182418, 3162515, 3162515, 3305224, 3305224, 3305224, 3305224, 
3520799, 6386072, 6803909, 6803909, 6803909, 7627720, 8193884, 
8193884, 9554461, 9766494, 9766494, 9853980, 9853980, 9853980
), Term = c("Cyclophosphamide", "Daunorubicin", "Cytosine arabinoside", 
"Vincristine", "AMSA", "Azacytidine", "Ara-C", "Amsacrine", "-C", 
"5-azacytidine", "AZA", "Daunorubicin", "Mithramycin", "Hydroxyurea", 
"Retinol", "Retinol palmitate", "Cytosine arabinoside", "Daunorubicin", 
"Amsacrine", "Cytosine arabinoside", "Cytarabine", "Anthracyclines", 
"Cytosine arabinoside", "Daunorubicin", "Thioguanine", "Cyclophosphamide", 
"Rifampicin", "CR", "Doxorubicin", "Cytarabine", "6-thioguanine", 
"Bilirubin", "Fluconazol", "Ofloxacin", "Taxol", "Aclarubicin", 
"Etoposide", "Mitoxantrone", "Cytarabine", "Etoposide"), Class = c("Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical", 
"Chemical", "Chemical", "Chemical"), MESH = c("MESH:D003520", 
"MESH:D003630", "MESH:D003561", "MESH:D014750", "MESH:D000677", 
"MESH:D001374", "MESH:D003561", "MESH:D000677", "MESH:D002244", 
"MESH:D001374", "MESH:D001379", "MESH:D003630", "MESH:D008926", 
"MESH:D006918", "MESH:D014801", "MESH:C014794", "MESH:D003561", 
"MESH:D003630", "MESH:D000677", "MESH:D003561", "MESH:D003561", 
"MESH:D018943", "MESH:D003561", "MESH:D003630", "MESH:D013866", 
"MESH:D003520", "MESH:D012293", "MESH:D002857", "MESH:D004317", 
"MESH:D003561", "MESH:D013866", "MESH:D001663", "MESH:D015725", 
"MESH:D015242", "MESH:D017239", "MESH:D015250", "MESH:D005047", 
"MESH:D008942", "MESH:D003561", "MESH:D005047")), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L), class = "data.frame")
```

My goal is to find out PMID which has single MESH term , then more than one MESH term such as double or triple MESH on multiple PMID.

For example for single MESH term I filter using this.

```
MESH_D003561 = filter(Only_mesh, MESH  %in% c("MESH:D003561"))
MESH_D003630 = filter(Only_mesh, MESH  %in% c("MESH:D003630"))
```

The if i wanted to see how many PMID has both the above MESH term such as `'MESH:D003561' and 'MESH:D003630'`

I tried this

```
x <- dplyr::filter(Only_mesh, MESH == "MESH:D003561" & MESH == "MESH:D003630")
```

I see no output what i understand is that to use 'AND' condition I need to use two diffrent column in a dataframe.

One of the long way is I filter each MESH term individually and then run intersect to find out PMID which contain both the MESH term.

But I would be glad if any suggestion or help how can i subset or filter based from the single column condition using "AND" as my operator.

Comment: You are asking for rows where MESH equals one thing AND equals another thing. A row can only match one of these at a time, so using AND returns FALSE for every row. I think you meant OR. Replace your `&` with a `|`

Comment: no i need and not OR ..because i want the PMID to see if it contain two different mesh term together " using AND returns FALSE for every row." yes that is what i observed..for example this 'MESH:D003561' and 'MESH:D003630' two different MESH ID associated to single PMID which is this 1691132..so would be using the AND condition if im correct

Comment: PesKchan I think maybe we misunderstand each other. Please see my answer for a solution.

Comment: no now i feel my question was bit confusing but your answer will get my job done perhaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `group_by(PMID)` first, then filter according to whether both MESH terms are present within that PMID:

```r
library(dplyr)

Only_mesh %>% 
  group_by(PMID) %>% 
  filter(any(MESH == "MESH:D003561") & any(MESH == "MESH:D003630")) %>%
  filter(MESH == "MESH:D003561" | MESH == "MESH:D003630")

#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   PMID [4]
#>      PMID Term                 Class    MESH        
#>     <dbl> <chr>                <chr>    <chr>       
#> 1 1691132 Daunorubicin         Chemical MESH:D003630
#> 2 1691132 Cytosine arabinoside Chemical MESH:D003561
#> 3 1691134 Ara-C                Chemical MESH:D003561
#> 4 1691134 Daunorubicin         Chemical MESH:D003630
#> 5 2031969 Cytosine arabinoside Chemical MESH:D003561
#> 6 2031969 Daunorubicin         Chemical MESH:D003630
#> 7 3305224 Cytosine arabinoside Chemical MESH:D003561
#> 8 3305224 Daunorubicin         Chemical MESH:D003630
```

Comment: Great answer.  I imagine the OP would want `distinct(PMID)` instead of `filter(MESH == "MESH:D003561" | MESH == "MESH:D003630")`

Comment: i wanted this as my final output ..where i wanted to See if the two MESH terms are present together in how many PMIDs together... `intersect(MESH_D003561$PMID, MESH_D003630$PMID)
1                                         1691132
2                                         1691134
3                                         2031969
4                                         3305224'

Comment: @MichaelDewar I wanted if Im looking for two MESH term how many PMID contains both the MESH term together as i have shown "1691132,1691134, 2031969 ,3305224" these PMID contain my both desired MESH term which i got when i filter the MESH term individually and  intersect to look for

Comment: I can achieve my objective by this way by taking the unique PMID which are found using @Allan code which gives me 4 PMID which contains both my MESH term

Comment: Yes.  This was the purpose of my comment.